# root controller error issues

Tags: ios, xcode

i'm trying to make an app that uses tabbed browsing. I can't figure out how to properly designate my root controller and xcode keeps giving me this error

"2013-10-13 18:51:56.688 FoxSays[23795:a0b] Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch"

the app launches but just dispays a white screen.  I've been told that this is because xcode cannot determine which screen it is supposed to display.

I'll post the code that i have in hopes that someone can help me.  there is some random unfinished stuff in there but right now i'm just trying to get it to display before i go any farther.  Thanks in advance.

```
//
//  FSAppDelegate.h
//  FoxSays
//
//  Created by Scott Pfeiffer on 10/1/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Bradley. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface FSAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

.

```
//
//  FSAppDelegate.m
//  FoxSays
//
//  Created by Scott Pfeiffer on 10/1/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Bradley. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import "FSAppDelegate.h"

@implementation FSAppDelegate



- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;

    //parse key
    [Parse setApplicationId:@"cG4arrkdJdTSHMwczQ4EQ7Lhj1qWjnoGDjGxtVZg"
                  clientKey:@"xVgThu6c55mm6e0TOmBLc4u5T4KCV4yqReYkekUP"];

    //parse analytics
    [PFAnalytics trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions];
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

@end
```

.

```
//
//  FSHomeViewController.h
//  FoxSays
//
//  Created by Scott Pfeiffer on 10/1/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Bradley. All rights reserved.
//

#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
#import "FSItemStore.h"
#import "FSItem.h"

@interface FSHomeViewController : UITabBarController

- (IBAction)playAudio:(id)sender;

@end
```

.

```
 //
    //  FSHomeViewController.m
    //  FoxSays
    //
    //  Created by Scott Pfeiffer on 10/1/13.
    //  Copyright (c) 2013 Bradley. All rights reserved.
    //

    #import "FSHomeViewController.h"
    #import "FSItem.h"
    #import "FSItemStore.h"

    @interface FSHomeViewController ()

    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *playAudio;

    @end

    @implementation FSHomeViewController

    - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
    {
        self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
        if (self) {
            // Custom initialization
        }
        return self;
    }



    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    - (IBAction)playAudio:(id)sender {
        AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
        NSString *audioPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Woof" ofType:@"mp3"];
        NSURL *audioURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioPath];
        NSError *audioError = [[NSError alloc] init];
        audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioURL error:&audioError];

        if (!audioError) {
            [audioPlayer play];
            NSLog(@"Woof!");
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Error!");
        }
    }



    @end
```

.

```
//
//  FSAnimalsViewController.h
//  FoxSays
//
//  Created by Scott Pfeiffer on 10/1/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Bradley. All rights reserved.
//

#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "FSDetailViewController.h"

@interface FSAnimalsViewController : UITableViewController
{
}
@end
```

.

```
//
//  FSAnimalsViewController.m
//  FoxSays
//
//  Created by Scott Pfeiffer on 10/1/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Bradley. All rights reserved.
//

#import "FSAnimalsViewController.h"
#import "FSItemStore.h"
#import "FSItem.h"

@implementation FSAnimalsViewController
- (id)init
{
    // Call the superclass's designated initializer
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    if (self)
    {
        UINavigationItem *n = [self navigationItem];

        [n setTitle:@"FoxSays"];

        // Create a new bar button item that will send
        // addNewItem: to ItemsViewController

        [[self navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:[self editButtonItem]];

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[self tableView] reloadData];
}


- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    return [self init];
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    FSDetailViewController *detailViewController = [[FSDetailViewController alloc] init];

    NSArray *items = [[FSItemStore defaultStore] allItems];
    FSItem *selectedItem = [items objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    // Give detail view controller a pointer to the item object in row
    [detailViewController setItem:selectedItem];

    // Push it onto the top of the navigation controller's stack
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:detailViewController
                                           animated:YES];
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[[FSItemStore defaultStore] allItems] count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Set the cell identifier
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"BasicCell";

    // Reuse the cell from the identifier
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell if it doesn't exist
    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Log the row for debugging
    NSLog(@"%d", [indexPath row]);

    // Get object from store
    FSItem *item = [[[FSItemStore defaultStore] allItems] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    // Set label to from property in object
    [[cell textLabel] setText:[item title]];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: sorta solved my problem.  i was dabbling and added another view controller which apparently worked.  I can now see the tabs at the bottom of the screen and they seem to work however it gives me this message "Two-stage rotation animation is deprecated. This application should use the smoother single-stage animation."  I guess my next problem is that one of my screens is supposed to have a button on it that i can click.  Its there in the storyboard but when i run the app it just displays a black screen? why is that and what can i do to fix it.  I can post code again if needed.

Answer (score 0):

In the appDelegate, create a member of your main root controller

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) FSHomeViewController * homeViewController
```

Then before the line

```
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Add:

```
homeViewController = [[FSHomeViewController alloc] init];
self.window.rootViewController = homeViewController
```

Don't forget to include the headers -
In "appDelegate.h"

```
@class FSHomeViewController
```

and in "appDelegate.m"

```
#import "FSHomeViewController"
```

Comment: i added and ran it.  Build fails with the following errors, "use of undeclared identifier 'homeViewController' and unknown receiver 'FSHomeViewController'.

Comment: In your appDelegate.h, add @class FSHomeViewController
And in your appDelegate.m add import "FSHomeViewController.h"

Comment: i tinkered and found a workable solution however i tried to implement yours to see if it made things smoother. the whole app crashes now! ahhhhh.

Comment: :( Do you mind posting what your appDelegate.h and .m look like now?

Comment: i would be happy to! I should probably explain my workable solution first.  I guess inexperience me didn't create a view controller for the tab bar controller. the FSHomeController was the tab that i wanted the app to open in.  Once i created a new view controller the app launched although the first tab's screen was black and second didn't' work for unrelated reasons, at least i got the tabs. i don't know how to do code with the comment limits. thoughts?